# ServiceStack ORMLIte : Id is necessary

Tags: c#, orm, ormlite-servicestack

I read on couple of articles that while using ORMLite, our objects must have Id property. One of the article is here:

> https://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/OrmLite

However, I created a class without Id property and tried serializing and deserializing it and ORMLite did it without any problems. So what feature exactly necessitates the Id property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are several API's in [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) which rely on a primary key which will be either:

- A property annotated with the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute
- A property named `Id`
- Otherwise the first property is considered to be the primary key

Some of OrmLite API's that rely on a primary key is:

- `db.Update(entity)` - updates all fields except the primary key which is used as a filter
- `db.Delete(entity)` - uses the primary key as a filter
- `db.SingleById(id)` - uses the primary key as a filter